# Webpack not installing on linux

Tags: node.js, linux, webpack

Recently i changed my environment from windows 10 to backbox linux 4.5.1 but i have tried to install webpack using `npm` several times . It never installs it gives these errors. Any help ?

```
 verbose tar unpack /home/dove/.npm/webpack/1.12.13/package.tgz
34 silly lockFile 27155615-tar-usr-lib-node-modules-webpack tar:///usr/lib/node_modules/webpack
35 verbose lock tar:///usr/lib/node_modules/webpack /home/dove/.npm/27155615-tar-usr-lib-node-modules-webpack.lock
36 silly lockFile 5c48f9fd--npm-webpack-1-12-13-package-tgz tar:///home/dove/.npm/webpack/1.12.13/package.tgz
37 verbose lock tar:///home/dove/.npm/webpack/1.12.13/package.tgz /home/dove/.npm/5c48f9fd--npm-webpack-1-12-13-package-tgz.lock
38 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '775', '664' ]
39 error Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack'
39 error  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack']
39 error   errno: 3,
39 error   code: 'EACCES',
39 error   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack',
39 error   fstream_type: 'Directory',
39 error   fstream_path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack',
39 error   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
39 error   fstream_stack:
39 error    [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
39 error      '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
39 error      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)' ] }
40 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
41 error System Linux 4.2.0-30-generic
42 error command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "webpack@1.12.13"
43 error cwd /home/dove/projects/yulu
44 error node -v v0.10.37
45 error npm -v 1.4.28
46 error path /usr/lib/node_modules/webpack
47 error fstream_path /usr/lib/node_modules/webpack
48 error fstream_type Directory
49 error fstream_class DirWriter
50 error code EACCES
51 error errno 3
52 error stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack'
53 error fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
53 error fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53
53 error fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
54 verbose exit [ 3, true ]
```

Comment: i noticed i think i just had to update my node and npm

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is about trying to install npm without sudo privileges since it gave an access error.

"Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/webpack'"

you should try to run your command with prefix of "sudo"

sudo "your-command"

Also you can try this command too.
npm config set unsafe-perm=true

There is a discussion about this error in github you might want to check it out.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/14